# How to catch the user red-handed if a forbidden word is entered?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to restrict the user somewhat regarding the username they can use, based on length and context.

Here, I am trying to make my username label red when a forbidden word is found when the user leaves the current textbox.

Although the code looks just fine to me, it seems like it completely ignores the forbidden words and makes the label green anyway if the other criteria a met. What is wrong with my code?

```
var username = document.forms.LogInForm.username;
username.onblur = function() {

    var forbiddenWords = ["fff, dddd, aaa, rrrr, oooo"];
    var regex;
    var username_value = this.value.split('');

    for (var a = 0; a < forbiddenWords.length; a++) {
        regex = new RegExp('\\b' + forbiddenWords[a] + '\\b');
        if (username_value[username_value.length - 1] === "-" || username_value[username_value.length - 1] === "_") {
            console.log('Username cannot end in dash (-) or underscore (_). We removed it for you!');
            this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
        }
        else if (this.value.length < 4) {
            console.log('Username cannot be less than 4 characters');
            document.getElementById('username_label').style.color = "red";
        }
        else if (username.value.search(regex) >= 0) {
            console.log('Username contains swearing word. Please, remove it');
            document.getElementById('username_label').style.color = "red";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('username_label').style.color = "green";
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems like basic logic flaw that you aren't keeping track if any instance fails before last and last doesn't. Style is solely dependent on last instance only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var forbiddenWords = ["fff, dddd, aaa, rrrr, oooo"];
```

is most likely a mistake and should read

```
var forbiddenWords = ["fff", "dddd", "aaa", "rrrr", "oooo"];
```

You want an array of separate strings, not a one element array containing string which has some commas and spaces as content.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't use `\b`. If you use `\b` the user could just type a swear word then add any character and the regex will not find anything.

Also, if the last forbidden word is not found validation color shows as passed because of your else statement. You should have a separate loop for forbidden words only, and mark a value as valid or invalid and display colors based on that.